# Black&White Camera Capture WinJS

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, photo, winjs

Is it possible to open the camera capture and force it to take black&white pictures?

Comment: Couldn't you just convert the picture yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CameraCaptureUI API doesn't provide the ability to change the color/BW of the camera, but you can add a media capture filter to make the change.

This SDK sample should give you what you need...be aware that to add the grayscale filter requires a C++ project (which is included in the sample):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using C#. I'm trying to convert the picture by myself. It would be nice to have that out-of-the-box.

Comment: While it might be nice, as far as I am aware, it doesn't exist. Also, the title of your question indicates WinJS, which is why I posted the JavaScript and C++ sample. The same link, however, also includes code for C# and C++.

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is that I'm using C# and JavaScript. Your answer is helpful

Comment: Glad to help...the samples are usually the first place I go any time I'm looking for an example of a given piece of functionality. There's a wealth of information in the SDK samples.